# Dart: forEach method parameter accepts void but even returning int works

Tags: flutter, dart

In `iterable.dart` file, code for `forEach` is:

```
void forEach(void f(E element)) {
  for (E element in this) f(element);
}
```

You can see, `forEach` parameter accepts a method and its return type should be `void` but following code just works fine without any error:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
list.forEach((item) {
  print(item);
  return true; // should show an error
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback you pass to `forEach()` would be inferred as a `bool Function(int)`, and `List<int>.forEach()` expects a `void Function(int)`.  This is accepted since `T Function()` is considered a subtype of `void Function()`; `T Function()` is substitutable anywhere `void Function()` is used.

Comment: Thanks again sir, but what about `void f() {return true;}` showing error? According to your last line, `void Function()` can always be substituted with `T Function()`, so my code shouldn't have any error.

Comment: `void f() { return true; }` is not substituting a `T Function()` for a `void Function()`.  It declares a `void Function()`, and the analyzer can see that the `void Function()` attempts to return a value.  This is different than doing `void Function() f = () { return true; };`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in dart when you use the void return type with a function , the return type could be void or anything else
for example :

```
main()=>print(function() as int); // the output is 12
void function()=>12;
```

in this example the void function returns a value

example 2:

```
class Super {

void function(){}

}

class Child extends Super{

@override
int function(){
 return 10;
}
```

you can override a function that have a type of void and change the type of the function to anything else.

Comment: I think because you can having more flexibility , and it will not harm